# Express Accept-Ranges header for streaming

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have an Express site, and one of the routes is built to stream video. I'm setting the `accept-ranges` header (to "bytes"), via `res.set("Accept-Ranges","bytes")`.  I'm even able to console.log out `res.get("Accept-Ranges")` before the response ends, which yields "bytes".

However, when I use another Node process to try to "get" that route, the header comes back "none". Strangely, it does work as expected when I run the Express site on my local machine (Windows 7, Node 0.10.22), but not when published to my testing box (Ubuntu 12.04, Node 0.10.22).

I suspect that it's getting over-ridden by some middleware, but I've tried removing everything I don't absolutely need, and even adding my own custom middleware that adds the header, itself. Neither thing worked.

Comment: do you see the header with `curl -vI http://localhost:3000` (with appropriate url)

Comment: I just tested a skeleton app on OS X, Windows and Ubuntu, and I don’t see anything that would be stripping out that header. Is your Ubuntu app proxied behind something else, like nginx?

Comment: Well... thank you for the proper curl command! That definitely got me pointed in the right direction.  When I make the curl request from another machine in the DMZ, it comes back right, but from my own machine, it comes back wrong! So, I set up an SSH tunnel on my local machine into the DMZ test server, and even the little Node test program I built works correctly through the tunnel.

It currently looks like we have a network situation.  I hesitate to mark this as the answer yet, but I'm going to test more on Monday. I feel a little more sane, though!